# Comparing polygon areas across simple feature collections

Tags: r, area, sf, stars, terra

I currently have three simple feature objects created from different shapefiles in R using the `sf` package. These three objects have all been projected to the same coordinate system using `st_transform()`. Each of these objects contains an attribute column titled `class`, which has information on the land cover type of every polygon geometry. The `class` names are consistent across the simple feature objects to ensure consistency in comparison.

However, I know that these shapefiles were digitized from historical maps of different spatial scales. My question, somewhat theoretical is - can I compute areas of different polygons in each simple feature collection and compare them? For example, if I computed the area of polygons of `class1` in object1, can I compare it to the same `class1` in object 2?

Happy to provide reproducible data if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare, of course. But I suppose your question is how much of the change you find may be caused by differences in accuracy. That will probably always involve some judgment call based on how much change you see, the relative quality of the maps, and the distribution of the classes; and based on general knowledge about the study system.

Some patterns are much more sensitive to changes in scale than others. For example, if you have many small "islands" of one class inside another class versus two well-separated classes. I suppose you could try to simplify the more accurate data and estimate the effect and use that as a "confidence interval". There could be different approaches to that. One could be to simplify polygons, or to rasterize and then aggregate using the modal value. See below for some ideas, but I think one can only address your question meaningfully by working with the actual data.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.5.28
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
values(v) <- NULL
v$class <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3)
v <- aggregate(v, "class")
plot(v, "class")
 
cbind(v[["class"]], area=expanse(v, "km"))
#  class     area
#1     a 768.7971
#2     b 929.3158
#3     c 866.6977
 
# simplify and remover overlaps
x <- simplifyGeom(v, 0.02) |> erase()
plot(x, "class")
 
cbind(x[["class"]], area=expanse(x, "km"))
#  class     area
#1     a 727.4593
#2     b 921.0105
#3     c 888.0171
```

You could do more such as removing small holes (of one class inside another, see `?fillHoles`) and fill gaps (see ?`gaps`)

Using a raster:

```
r <- rast(v, res=.001)
r <- rasterize(v, r, "class")
sz <- cellSize(r, unit="km")
zonal(sz, r, sum)
#  class     area
#1     a 769.1007
#2     b 929.2446
#3     c 866.5936
#4  <NA>   0.0000
 
 
a <- aggregate(r, 30, "modal")
sza <- cellSize(a, unit="km")
zonal(sza, a, sum)
#  class     area
#1     a 980.3433
#2     b 966.0461
#3     c 988.2875
#4  <NA>   0.0000
```

Or perhaps, to keep the total area constant

```
va <- as.polygons(a) |> crop(v)
cbind(va[["class"]], area=expanse(va, "km"))
#  class     area
#1     a 760.1835
#2     b 908.8691
#3     c 895.7540
```

While here there is little effect that might be different with your data if you tweak it enough.

Comment: Thank you so much @Robert Hijmans! I would like to follow up on your point about the actual data and the scale. If I can expand on what I wrote - to give you some context, I have three maps whose scales have been written as 1:12000, 1:24000 and 1:63000. So the last map is at 30m spatial resolution and rest are at 12m and 6m respectively. Is it a wise approach to simply compare the polygonal areas without resampling, as you have shown above?

Comment: I do not think that one can answer this question based on the information you provide as it depends on the spatial pattern.  But the above may give some ideas about how to investigate this.